# Rotating a UISplitViewController upon dismissing a modal UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I've created a Master Detail Application using the iOS 5 SDK, intending to have a UIViewController displayed modally when the device is portrait, and a UISplitViewController when the device is landscape.

The modal VC gets dismissed when rotating to landscape using the following:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)){
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

but the UISplitViewController never gets the rotation event so ends up in it's portrait "mode" within the landscape window.

I've tried triggering a rotation in viewWillAppear in the DetailViewController like so:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)) {
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    }
}
```

, have tried calling the SplitViewController's `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, and have also tried calling `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` on the SplitViewController from my modal but none have any effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do all of this? Why not just use a `UISplitViewController for both orientations? When in portrait, the split view controller will only show the detail view. The user can bring up the master when needed. When in landscape, the split view controller shows both at once. What benefit do you perceive by having your extra modal view controller in portrait?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Pushing another detail view completely skipped my mind. I initially wanted the modal view as I have no need for the master view in portrait, and preferred not to have the title/nav bar showing, but I guess this way is much simpler. Thanks again :)